# Selecting Hexagons around a radius

Tags: c#, list, hexagonal-tiles

I have a map made of hexagons. When a hexagon is clicked on which a troop resides, other hexagons around the clicked one should be highlighted based on the troop's range variable.

I have tried quite a few methods on my own, but failed. I can't seem to get a list with the correct ones highlighted. In this example I will be using a troop of a range of 2 tiles.

The method I have tried to implement is as following:
There are 3 lists.

- Open list contains nodes to be expanded by 1
- Close list contains nodes that will be highlighted
- remove list contains nodes that have already been expanded

I followed the following algorithm:

1. Add the start node to all lists.
2. Expand the nodes in open list by 1 tile.
3. Remove the nodes within open list using remove list.
4. add open list nodes to closed list.
5. clear remove list.
6. copy open list contents to remove list.
7. Repeat for whatever the range of the troop is.

My goal is to highlight a hex tiles of radius r, around the clicked tile; r = troop range.

Im quite lost, and I was probably doing some obvious mistakes. Any help will be appreciated!

(Below is the code that I made)

```
private List<string> expand(List<string> open, bool odd)
    {
        List<string> newopen = new List<string>();
        int oddEven = 1;
        if (odd == false)
        {
            oddEven = -1;
        }
        foreach (string s in open)
        {
            string[] rc = s.Split('.'); //row + col of the current hex
            int Row = int.Parse(rc[0]);
            int Col = int.Parse(rc[1]);

            for (int r = 1; r >= -1; r--)
            {
                for (int c = -1; c <= 1; c++)
                {
                    if (!((r == oddEven && c != 0) || (r== 0 && c == 0)))
                    {
                        if (((Row + r) > -1 && (Col + c) > -1) && ((Row + r) < 9 && (Col + c) < 18)) //mapcheck
                        {
                            if (Hexmap[Row + r, Col + c] == '-') //mapcheck
                            {
                                newopen.Add((Row + r).ToString() + "." + (Col + c).ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return newopen;
    }
    private void Remove(ref List<string> rem, ref List<string> open)
    {
        foreach (string s in rem)
        {
            open.Remove(s);
        }
    }
    private void Add(ref List<string> closed, ref List<string> open)
    {
        foreach (string s in open)
        {
            closed.Add(s);
        }
    }

    private void TroopSelect(int row, int col, int range)
    {
        bool odd = true;
        if ((row % 2) == 0)
        {
            odd = false;
        }

        List<string> open = new List<string>();
        List<string> close = new List<string>();
        List<string> remove = new List<string>();

        open.Add(row.ToString() + "." + col.ToString());
        close.Add(row.ToString() + "." + col.ToString());
        remove.Add(row.ToString() + "." + col.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
        {
            open = expand(open, odd); //row and col of the current point being checked --- REMOVE ROW COL, find it out from the list within the function
            Remove(ref remove, ref open); //remove from open the remove hex values
            Add(ref close, ref open); //add to closed what's in open
            remove.Clear();  //clear remove
            remove = open; //set remove the same as open
        }

        foreach (string s in close)
        {
            string[] rc = s.Split('.'); //row + col of the current hex
            int Row = int.Parse(rc[0]);
            int Col = int.Parse(rc[1]);

            Hexagons.Add(new PointF(Row, Col));
        }
    }

    private void CheckTroop(int row, int col)
    {
        if (Hexmap[row, col] == 'o') //it's a friendly troop
        {
            foreach (Troops t in playertroops)
            {
                if (t.row == row && t.column == col)
                {
                    TroopSelect(row, col, t.range);
                    this.battlegrid.Invalidate();                   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void battlegrid_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int row, col;
        PointToHex(e.X, e.Y, HexHeight, out row, out col); //gets the hex in the x/y position
        CheckTroop(row, col);

        //this.Invalidate();
    }
```

Below are also two images:                            (Ignore the rock in the background!)

1. First of troop range = 1, works ok
2. Second image of troop range = 2, doesn't work ok
   [image: troop range 1]
   [image: troop range 2]

Thanks once again for any help.

Comment: This looks like it'd be so much easier with proper data types instead of strings.

Comment: Are you using an inside radius (to a side) or outside radius (to a vertex)?

Comment: each hexagon has a row and column value which is what I've been using for radius